# Implementing SendGrid Email IP whitelisting using c#

Tags: c#, sendgrid, whitelist

I'm using sendgrid mail server with ASP.NET application. And I'm facing issues with email delivery in recent days. Many emails are bounced and deferred.
Looking to implement IP whitelisting concept in my application, But I have no idea where to start.

**This is my code to send Email using SendGrid** :

```cs
var apiKey = << MySendGridApiKey >>;

try
{
    var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
    objSendGridMessage.Subject = objSendGridMessage.Subject;
    var responses = await client.SendEmailAsync(objSendGridMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Please provide any idea to implement the whitelisting concept from C#.

Thanks...!

Comment: Bounces and deferrals are normal and not necessarily something you can fix. But to get the best deliverability, you need to employ SPF and DKIM. Have you done that?

Comment: No @Crowcoder, I have no idea about SPF and DKIM. How can I do that in SendGrid with c#?
Note: I can't go with the domain-based setting, because I will have new domain adding in the future and domain changes on the customer (recipient) email.

Comment: This is an industry standard practice so without it you risk deliverability issues and sender reputation problems. Your application cannot employ an allow list that will have any effect on recipient mail servers.